# Proving big theta notation?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I need a little guidance solving this problem.
I'm trying to show that for every base b > 1;

$(log_b n) = Θ(log _2 n)$

I know that for f(n) to be big-theta it needs to be BigO and BigOmega

So I start off by choosing base b = 2

- And solve BigO first:

BigO Definition: $ (∃K,C>0)(∀n>K) f(n) <= C*g(n)$

So we need to prove that $log_2 n <= ( C ) * ( log _2 n)$ for all n > k

I choose C = 1 and K = 1

$log_2 (n) <= ( 1 ) * ( log _2 n)$ for all n > 1

choose n = 2

$log_2 (2) <= ( 1 ) * ( log _2 2)$ for all n > 1

$log_2 (2) <= ( log _2 2)$  They are equal, so this is true, and will always be true for any n > 1. BigO is proven.

- Solve BigΩ

BigΩ Definition: $ (∃K,C>0)(∀n>K) f(n) >= C*g(n)$

we need to prove that $log_2 n >= ( C ) * ( log _2 n)$ for all n > k

I choose C = 1 and K = 1

$log_2 (n) >= ( 1 ) * ( log _2 n)$ for all n > 1

choose n = 2

$log_2 (2) >= ( 1 ) * ( log _2 2)$ for all n > 1

$log_2 (2) >= ( log _2 2)$  They are equal, so this is true, and will always be true for any n > 1. BigΩ is proven.

Therefore for base b = 2, they equal each other.

Now onto base b = 3.

- Solve BigO first:

We need to prove that $log_3 n <= ( C ) * ( log _2 n)$ for all n > k

choose C = 1, k = 1

$log_3 (n) <= ( 1 ) * ( log _2 n)$ for all n > 1

choose n = 2

$log_3 (2) <= ( log _2 2)$ is true, and will be true for any n > 1

- Solve BigΩ

prove that $log_3 n >= ( C ) * ( log _2 n)$ for all n > k

Can I choose C as a decimal? since if C = 1 , the RHS will always be larger.

I choose K = 1, C = .1

$log_3 (n) >= ( .1 ) * ( log _2 n)$ for all n > 1

choose n = 2

$log_3 (2) >= ( .1 ) * ( log _2 2)$ for all n > 1

$ .630 >= (.1)*(1)  $

$ .630 >= (.1) $  TRUE  big Omega has been proven

So I guess my question is: Is this method correct? Especially my last Big-Omega, and Is it okay to choose a C = that is a decimal like .1? as long as its > 0

Comment: You’re doing great so far, but here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr). You can reference it for tips on further beautifying your post.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it much too hard.

To show that
$(\log_b n) = Θ(\log _2 n)
$
you need to show that
there are positive
$u$ and $v$ such that
$u
\le \dfrac{\log_b n}{\log _2 n}
\le v
$.

But
$\log_b n
= \dfrac{\log_2 n}{\log_2 b}
$
so
$ \dfrac{\log_b n}{\log _2 n}
=\dfrac{\frac{\log_2 n}{\log_2 b}}{\log _2 n}
=\dfrac1{\log _2 b}
$
and this is all you need.

In fact,
the ratio is constant,
not just bounded.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm getting it. For any question trying to prove f(n) = Θ(g(n)) , can you say that you need to show it as u <= [ f(n) / g(n)  ] <= v where u and v are positive? When you simplify log2(n) / log2(b) into 1/log2(b), how does that prove that our original f(n) = theta( g(n) )? Are you showing that  log2(n) / log2(b)  can be simplified so that there is no n value ? and that would prove it to be big-theta

Comment: Right. The cases are: $f(n) =O(g(n))$ means $f(n)/g(n)$ is bounded above;$f(n) =\Omega(g(n))$ means $f(n)/g(n)$ is bounded below;$f(n) =\Theta(g(n))$ means $f(n)/g(n)$ is bounded both above and below;$f(n) =o(g(n))$ means $f(n)/g(n) \to 0$.